# How do I find and kill a single mosquito in the middle of the night?

Tags: home, pest-control

Many times a single mosquito will buzz in my ear at night (and bite me). I know if I kill it there won't be any others, but finding one is difficult.

Comment: Why is getting rid of one any different to getting rid of many?

Comment: @Chenmunka Because something like smoke or a fan is overkill. I don't need a shotgun, I need a sniper rifle (metaphorically).

Comment: Did you really counted how many mosquitoes are there ?

Comment: I don't know about finding it. I just cover my ear with the blanket, so I won't hear it any more.

Comment: +1 excellent question. I'm surprised of the down votes as I'm sure everyone has the annoyance of a mosquito keeping them up at night.

Comment: "If it's blood you're looking for, I can tell you I don't have any. But what I do have are a very particular set of skills, skills I have acquired over a very long career. Skills that make me a nightmare for mosquitos like you."

Comment: I've gone the rounds with this topic. point a fan over you while you sleep and VIOLÁ! Mosquitoes flounder in even the smallest breeze. They'll eventually give up.

Comment: Wait till the buzzing maximizes. Slap yourself in the ear, hard. If you're lucky, you kill the mosquito, if not - at least you couldn't hear it with that ear for a while.

Comment: I use the same method as @Headcrab but slightly smarter ^^. I lay in the bed on my back, using the cover to protect myself, neck included. Then I just simply try to sleep. The vampire can damage you (with bite or buzz) just coming close to your face, that make them pretty noisier 90% of the time and hearable a couple of seconds before landing. By instinct I quickly use a hand to smash them. The point will be pretty exact, there will be lot less air movement (so they don't slide away) and the impact with the ear (usually) will be softened by the cover. And you can come back to sleep easily 

Answer (score 41):

Killing a mosquito is easy (as you can see in the other answers). Finding it is the hard part. This is the easiest way I've found of locating a mosquito.

You need 2 light sources:

- a small lamp that will give enough light for you to move around the room.
- a powerful torch (flashlight)

To find a mosquito:

1. Switch off the lights, wait until you can hear the mosquito close by.
2. Switch on the small lamp.
3. Switch on the torch, and hold the torch so that the light beam is parallel to the wall. If a mosquito sits on the wall in the light beam, it's easy to spot because it will cast a large shadow. 
   If you can't find the mosquito right away, be patient. The mosquito will fly to a place where it's visible eventually.
   [image: Catch a mosquito]
4. Systematically check the walls in the room. When you're hunting the mosquito, make sure not to cast a shadow on the mosquito. The sudden shadow will make the mosquito fly away.
5. Kill using your favored method.

Comment: This one is my favored method

Comment: Another thing I've found is that the mosquitoes which make it to your bedroom have a tendency to hide in shadowy places and upside down, sometimes sideways and rarely right side up. So after switching on the light, be sure to search up in the top corners of the room, under the bed and behind furniture.

Answer (score 13):

Now that's something which you can use to kill **1** mosquito. Just simply target it and use this racket and that's too in the middle of the night. Its not the only option but its just my recommendation:

### Mosquito Killing Racket

Why to use this:

Just because it is re-chargeable you can first charge it and keep it beside you and whenever you find any mosquito you can target it and kill this with this racket.

You can use it by pressing that red button. While pressing it there will be some electric charges come at those nets and when any mosquito come in contact with those net it dies at that moment. Since there is one more layer of net to protect you from getting any damage from that and its also not that much risky. If by accident you touch it, it will give you just a little shock but its good to take precautions.

Since you said you have to kill it and so I recommend you this.

[image]

Comment: These are really good. The ones without the safety mesh and just horizontal wires are the best. Still though, it doesn't really solve the question because you have to find the single mosquito and don't really want to turn on the lights and go searching around while you're trying to sleep.

Comment: Isn't this a common sense?

Comment: This answer addresses *killing* a mosquito, but not *finding* it, which is the hard part.

Comment: A cheaper cost effective/instant way of doing this is to rub some oil (any oil) on to a wide steel plate (why steel? read on) and then fling your arms around to capture the mosquito. The mosquito once it comes in contact with the plate will stick to it because of the oil. Use steel plate because if you accidentally drop anything else, it will shatter and make a mess.

Comment: Again i would like to say that its not the only option, it is just my recommendation. There can be many method which you can try but in the middle of the night if I want to kill one mosquito then swinging this racket is much better (based on pure luck :P) rather than finding one single mosquito and then confirming it with your naked eyes and then killing it because few people are too lazy.

Comment: How does it work when the mosquito is on a wall?

Answer (score 12):

Get a [bug zapper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004R9VZ). I've usually seen these on porches but we stayed at a cabin in mosquitoville and naturally some mosquitoes snuck in. The first night it was bzzzz bzzzz in my ear all night. The next night I found a bug zapper and hung it inside the cabin right by the door. I never heard another mosquito at night for the next six nights.

The shock-racket is cool but the bug zapper is totally passive. And by passive I mean you don't need to wake up and swing a racket around!

[image]

Comment: There some evidence that bug zappers are not effective against mosquitos http://www.control-mosquitoes.com/#mf13

Comment: Apparently these kill more 'beneficial' and 'harmless' bugs than mosquitos based on some studies: http://www.ipm.iastate.edu/ipm/hortnews/1996/6-14-1996/bugzapper.html

Comment: @jimmyplaysdrums that study may be accurate in the environment - outside. OP is talking about inside; not many valuable water bugs and butterflies are flapping through.

Comment: Good point @jqning

Answer (score 8):

Just grab your pillow and wait... 
When the buzzing sound in your ears alert you, bam! Hit yourself with the pillow. The large area of impact will crush it.

Comment: Try not to give answers that cause self-harm please. This is a forum for life hacks and solutions that are meant to be practical and feasible. No jokes please.

Comment: @sindhus - Are you serious? I feel exactly the reverse. It is harmless. It is practical and feasible for the reasons succinctly stated.

Comment: A pillow is not harmful, it's a clean method that doesn't require any extra equipment.

Answer (score 5):

My way of doing it: I leave all the lights off and go in a smaller room (usually the bathroom) and this is where I turn the lights on.

Then the mosquito is attracted by the light (and by myself) so it comes in the bathroom. Then I close the door and in a smaller room, it's easier to locate it and kill it!

Comment: Is this really works?

Comment: It works for me. I often do not even bother to kill it, I just close the doors between me and the mosquito.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a mosquito net. If a mosquito (if it's slim) find its way into your net then you can easily corner and punish it.

Comment: Punish it ... Now that's scary ! :P

Answer (score 2):

One way I have tried and became successful many times is by analysis of behaviour of mosquitoes.Mosquitoes try to hide in areas such as shelf,almirah,beneath desks.Now you can create a situation for them.In light open the almirah a bit such that light slightly crosses the almirah.You may find mosquitoes usually sitting there.Dont waste time if you want to kill.Stamp them.
In shelves in one of the corners pile some waste like old boxes and bags.It acts as suitable place for mosquitoes to hide.When you air it you will find it flying.
If two three days have passed by and the mosquito is frustrating you.At the final day close the light and wait for the mosquito to arrive near your bed.Do what you want with him.

Comment: I agree they have their favourite places, but they might be different from room to room. Had one room where they liked to sit on the white wall in 2 m height, next to the window. Very easy to check before going to bed.

Answer (score 2):

I came here because there is a mosquito in my room that just attacked me and I've been walking around my room armed with a book and bug spray for the past 20 minutes trying to find it and it won't come out and fight like a man. I'm thinking do I open the door and let it fly out or is it too stupid to do that and if it is then what if more mozzies come in? I chose to keep the mozzie locked and I finally hunted the coward down and sprayed it with bug spray and IT DIED.

Hunting Techniques:

**Weapons -** books, spray, hands, electric bug killer, bug swat (usually when hunting mozzies I wack them with books and things that aren't mine

**Light -** you need light for locating the trespassing mozzie. It is impossible to find them in the dark except if you listen to their buzzing but I find that creepy.

Hope your mozzie gets the death penalty it DESERVES. Bye SSMFC (super secret mozzie fighting club)

Answer (score 1):

I too am guilty of entering into battle with a mosquito 1 on 1.... So I propose a combo of ideas, from above, that have worked for me....

First, -no- You mustn't hunt the pest it must be lured to you...

Second, -no- I havn't got 2 days to complete the mission...

My personal choice is the racket as well (mine runs on double A's; $ 6.00 @ Walgreen); it puts you on a fair playing field;| and execution by electrocution is very validating...

My personal source of fatal attraction is my ipad; the eerie glow in the otherwise total darkness seems to be truely, the forbidden fruit, irresistible for the vector to avoid, yet it crosses into the valley of the shadow of death...

Well anyway, happy hunting...

Answer (score 1):

Use a light source or water to attract bugs so that you don't have to go hunting around for them.

If a quick scan of Google search results is to be believed, waving your hand slowly over a plate of water under a low light source in a darkened room should attract flying bugs quite quickly.

Comment: Why would water attract a mosquito?

Answer (score 0):

If your main room light is recessed and your ceiling is low enough;

Turn on the light and hold your cupped hands underneath , close enough to require the bug to enter the hand trap to find its way closer to the light (careful not to get too close and burn hands or blind yourself!).

Wait until the annoying creature has entered the hand cup of doom, then clap.

Admittedly this is probably slower and requires more patience than some other suggestions but saves buying an electrified tennis racket or collecting a range of torches in your room.