# How to find a mosquito at night?

Tags: home, pest-control

Recently I'm suffering from a problem:

In the middle of the night, a mosquito just keep bzzzing in my ears, but when I move, it stops, but after a minute, it bzzzing again.

I've tried using mosquito repelling incense, it worked at first, but then after several days, the mosquito bzzz again. I tried turning on the lights in the bedroom to find, and I found the mosquito at first, but it flew too fast that it just disappear after < 0.5 sec.

I also bought this one:

[image]

But it doesn't help.

I also thought of buying a Mosquito Killing Racket, but it's hard to kill the mosquito in the middle of the night using this cause I can't find it.

I've also taken a look at this post:
[How do I find and kill a single mosquito in the middle of the night?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7454/how-do-i-find-and-kill-a-single-mosquito-in-the-middle-of-the-night)

Unfortunately the methods doesn't help very much.

So is there any other way to find the nasty mosquito at night?

Comment: If you look deeper to my question, you will notice I have already seen that post but those methods didn't help much @Hobbes

Comment: You're looking for solutions to the same problem, and you're already attracting answers that are just duplicates from the original question.

Comment: @User2012384 if the answers from the other question do not fix your problem, that is not justification to post the same question again. You should leave a comment or bounty on the other question to try and attract answers that will suit you.

Comment: I think the original form of the word 'buzz' had a u in it.

Comment: The CO2 you made when you breath attract Mosquitoes, turn off the light, sleep beside the wall and breath directly into the wall, after 5 min the CO2 between you and the wall will attract the mosquito, and you will find it on the wall, but mosquito are smart they know when you are a sleep or not, for that close your eyes and slow down your breath to slow down your heart rate, after 5 min look onto the wall you will find it there..

Answer (score 1):

1. Switch off the lights, wait until you can hear the mosquito close
   by.
2. Switch on the small lamp.
3. Switch on the torch, and hold the
   torch so that the light beam is parallel to the wall. ...
4. Systematically check the walls in the room.
5. Get rid of it

Comment: Hello, not quite understand step 3... what do you mean by "hold the torch so that the light beam is parallel to the wall".

Comment: See the original answer here: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/7952/5307

Answer (score 1):

Why to allow mosquitoes in the room at first place?
Prevent them from coming inside the room.
Using mosquito net allows air to flow as well as blocks mosquitoes.

[image]

If u are sticking to searching mosquito in dark then best solution would be to use 9V 6f22 battery connected to 2 x 4.5 volt LEDs. (Unlike 3 V led, These LEDs spread light instead of concentrating it.) Place it such that light will fall on mosquitoes and reflect back to you. Reason to use led than simply turning light on is that, led do not light walls to much extent as they are far than mosquitoes and thus mosquitoes are easily seen.By this you can easily spot and kill mosquitoes.

Comment: If you have multiple answers please post them separately

Answer (score 1):

When you've switched on the lights, be patient. The mosquito will fly to a place where it's visible eventually.

When you're hunting the mosquito, make sure not to cast a shadow on the mosquito. The sudden shadow will make the mosquito fly away.

Answer (score 0):

I usually turn on the lights in a different but small room (for example the bathroom) while keeping the lights of every other room switched off. It won't need more than 3 minutes for the mosquito to be inside. Once it's inside, close the door to trap it in this room and either leave it there or exterminate it.

Comment: Oh so you mean mosquitoes are attract to lights?

Comment: Of course they are! Almost every insect does that.

Comment: So why mosquito killing lamp can't attract it to go inside? I tried putting that in my bedroom but the mosquito still exist :(

Comment: Try to put the lamp somewhere outside your bedroom but visible from it. If you put that lamp inside your bedroom you will attract more mosquitos!

Comment: OK, thanks! I will give it a try tonight :)

Comment: Have a nice sleep!

Comment: By the way, do I need to turn off the light in the morning?\

Comment: If you meen the bathroom light, you can turn it off as soon as the mosquito is inside the bathroom. If you meen the lamp, yes there is no reason for it to be on in the morning

Comment: Mosquitoes are more attracted towards warm carbon dioxide which we exhale. your method won't work unless you bring large amount of CO2 in bathroom

Comment: @Fennekin, weirdly it does work for me. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score -1):

Let it suck your blood then it will get heavy and you can kill it so easily.

Comment: Yes, but first, I'll have to find out where the mosquito hides so I can kill it easily :(

Comment: @AmerYR try to donate blood to human race. please don't waste it on mosquitoes voluntarily. It may save someone's life one day