# How to better see mosquitoes?

Tags: home

In the summer, I am annoyed by small numbers of mosquitoes. Since they are not many, I just use an electric racket to take care of them.

The main issue I have with the racket is visibility: when a mosquito is in the room, it is hard to find. It happens often that I see it, but before I grab the racket, it disappears from my field of view, even if I try to follow it with my eyes. I have noticed that mosquitoes are much harder to track on dark backgrounds.

What can I do to my room to better see the mosquitoes? Repainting the walls and furniture in white is not an option.

Comment: For those of us that don't know what an electric racket is (me), please define it in other terms?

Comment: @stan its a tennis racket that has wires instead of strings they get electrical charge from batteries and shock the mozzie on contact

Comment: @JacquesRamsden A taser for bugs?

Comment: Jip https://www.google.co.za/search?q=mosquito+racket&client=ms-android-huawei&prmd=ivsn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCnvmzjJPdAhVLLsAKHY3GBxAQ_AUIESgB&biw=360&bih=524

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find and kill a single mosquito in the middle of the night?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7454/how-do-i-find-and-kill-a-single-mosquito-in-the-middle-of-the-night)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t do anything to your room. Just lie on the floor, face up. Ceilings are usually a fairly large expanse of plain white and the mosquito will have a hard time using it for camouflage.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt this amazing trick:
put a small amount of vinegar, wine or other fermented liquid in a glass, cover the glass with transparent wrap and open a few holes with a pen to avoid evaporation. Place glasses in corners of room or kitchen. Mosquitoes hate the strong scent of fermented liquids and they will go away and avoid your place.

Also consider to hide any single source of food for the mosquitoes: sugar, fruits, open rubbish cans.

There is this plant called citronella buy those and place them around the house.

No more mosquitoes.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me: Stand still and wait for the mosquito to land on your skin (it doesn't take long). Let it adjust itself and start sucking your blood, and then just smash it (if you do it before that it will likely just fly away). This way you don't actually need to see it at all (that is, you don't need to get out of bed, turn the lights on, etc).

Comment: And when smashing it, move the hand very slowly until it's 5-10 cm from the mosquito (and without putting a shadow on it). Then smash it very fast. (Then, no need to wait until it sucks your blood, which is an infection risk to rather avoid.)

Comment: "Let it adjust itself and start sucking your blood" WAAHHAA!!!

Answer (score -1):

Buy a cat, let the cat hunt and eat the mosquitoes, rub your cat.
Easy as f*** :D

Jokes aside, I once read here that putting a small light parallel to the wall will create a huge shadow of the mosquito when he lands. Have something in hand ready to smash it

Comment: That reminds me of the afternoon our cat came home with a (largely unharmed) huge dragonfly in his mouth, looking desperate and confused - could some of the humans please show him what to do with this thing?

Answer (score -2):

Use **NEON Light**  in dark corner.. It will attract mosquitoes and you will find them easily !!!

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! This sounds like a good idea, but your answer doesn't really tell us _why_ it would work, or have any other sources saying that it _does_ work. If you could add those, this would be a great post! Thank you!